# How to prevent making a empty zip file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am producing a zip of image files.But if image does not found then it generates an exception like `java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP file must have at least one entry` . I am handling the exception but an empty zip of 0 size is getting generated. So please help me to sort out this problem

```
    try {
        // create the ZIP file

        ZipOutputStream out = getOutputStream(subpart, destinationZipPath);

        /*
         * ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
         * destinationZipPath));
         */
        // compress the files
        LOGGER.error("zip creation is started @" + new Date().toString());
        for (String fileNameDB : filesTobeZipped) {
            // To check duplication of filename in zip creation
            if (!filesHash.containsKey(fileNameDB)) {
                filesHash.put(fileNameDB, fileNameDB);
                File f = new File(sourceFolder + fileNameDB);
                // to chk file is exists on physical location or not
                if (f.exists()) {
                    if (fileCount >= batchFileLimit) {
                        out.close();
                        subpart++;
                        out = getOutputStream(subpart, destinationZipPath);
                        fileCount = 0;
                        // overallSize=0;
                    }
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
                    // add ZIP entry to output stream
                    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(f.getName()));
                    // transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    // complete the entry
                    out.closeEntry();
                    in.close();
                    fileCount++;
                } else {
                }
            }

        }
        // complete the ZIP file
        out.close(); // Exception if fileCount=0;
        return true;
        // return zipfile;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just create the ZIP stream after you detected the first existing file. Just like

```
ZipOutputStream out = null;

for (String fileNameDB : filesTobeZipped) {
    if (new File(fileNameDB).exists()) {
        if (out == null) {
            out= ZipOutputStream out = getOutputStream(subpart, destinationZipPath);
        }

        // do other operations
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
ZipOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = getOutputStream(subpart, destinationZipPath);
    ...
    out.close(); // Exception if fileCount=0;
    return true;
    // return zipfile;
} catch (IOException ex) {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
    destinationZipPath.toFile().delete(); // Or whatever is appropriate.
    return false;
}
```

Maybe nicer would be to have a try-catch in the loop. And checking the number of files.

Then you could use a try-with-resources.